# Calculate in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-calculator

I need some help with a raster file in ArcMap. The raster is a validation file for a classification that should follow after. Therefore, I need to "cut" the upper and lower 5% of the data in the raster. My histogram looks like this:

[image]

I want to solve this in ArcMap because it failed at loading it into RStudio as the program cannot allocate the vector because of its size. My aim is to have a new value range that I can use for a classification.

Does someone know a way to do this?

Comment: Is that 5% of *cell area* on both ends or 5% of the *value range* on both ends? When you figure out the precise lower and upper limit you can use ExtractByAttributes http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000029000000 to extract the in-between values if you have access to the spatial analyst extension.

Comment: It is about the cell area. In fact the new value range is the result I want to get. Your solution would work the other way round when I still know the new value range. Do you know a solution for the calculation of this values as well?

Comment: It sounds like you need to compile a list of values and occurrences, sort and select cells (in Excel) until the sum of counts = 1/20 of the total sum of cells revealing the min/max bounds of 'real' data. Not something I'd like to do on a large raster. I know of no simple way to achieve this; how fluent are you in python?

Comment: Hmm, that is not what I wanted to hear, haha! :)

Comment: I once had a course in Python but yeah, I hoped that I could handle the problem in ArcMap because I don't achieve to get the list in Excel :(

Comment: Convert it to integer, using Int(R*100). Table of result will have enough info for your task.